Latching Relay causes RFDuino to disconnect
I have the following set up:

The goal is control the power of the Pi Zero with Bluetooth. I'm using an old RFDuino (which isn't produced anymore but it's programmable with the Arduino IDE) to control the latching relay.
However, when I turn the Pi on, RFDuino/Bluetooth temporarily disconnects. I'm guessing some feedback from the relay. Turning it off doesn't cause it and when the Pi is not attached, it also doesn't happen.
I already tried adding a capacitor over the power supply but that doesn't help.
I've read about flyback diodes but I don't know how that would work with a latching relay since I need to reverse polarity to turn off the Pi.
Another idea would be to switch polarity in 2 steps, first bring both pins to 0 before switching around.
Any help is appreciated.

You trying to source > 60 mA of current from a GPIO and sink the same ammount, I think that you exceeding current limits for port and GPIO. Add some capacitance close to RFDuino (to store local energy for transients), also try switch relay with transistor, also don’t forget to add fly back diode, or even TVS for faster and more reliable switches. If you have any questions about suggested schematic, feel free to ask.

You also do need a freewheel diode, in this case maybe a bidirectional TVS would work fine for your purposes.

Maybe instead of all this use a plain old relay with a plain old flyback diode, then between the RF board and the relay place a flip flop or latch IC which sufficient drive strength for the coil.

I don't want to use a plain old relay because that would require power while it's on and I want to save on energy.

You could consider also a two-coil latching relay (with two diodes), and if current too great, a transistor with sufficient drive.

"that would require power while it's on and I want to save on energy" So use a MOSFET, not relays.
